# Vector space made of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I'm with a doubt. I'm not a mathematician so this is a simple question.

So, I know that the canonical basis of a vector space grade $ \le2 $ is $B =\{1,t,t^2\} $, my question is because in some test I'm doing, the affirmative appeared:

"A vector space made of all polynomials of grade $ \le2 $ have a basis made of $3$ second grade vectors"

So is it correct to say this? On this case, the basis would be $B = \{1 +0t+0t^2,  t+0t^2, t²\}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $1$ has degree $0$ and the polynomial $t$ has degree $1$. So, your answer is not correct.

A basis made of polynomials with degree $2$ is, for instance $\{t^2,t^2+1,t^2+t\}$.

Comment: você é brasileiro? :D So, thanks for the answer. I can see now, the basis $\{t^2,t^2+1,t^2+t\} $can generate any polynomials too. So the affirmative is correct too.

Comment: I am Portuguese.

Comment: Yah, I saw now. Sorry. I'm Brazilian. :). Felicidades!